# How to prove $(2^n)>(n^2+1) $ by induction $n \geq 5$

Tags: inequality, induction

Today I'm trying to find a solution with induction to this problem, so far this is what I could do:

$$(n+1)^2+1 = n^2+2n+2$$

$$2^{n+1} = 2*2^n > 2n^2 > 2n^2 +2$$

I was searching around and I found this:

(1) $2n^2 > n^2 + 2n + 2$
but I don't seem to understand where is the proof that (1) is true.

Comment: The inequality is not true for $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$ and $4$.

Comment: You have a typo or something in your attempt.  You said $2n^2>2n^2+2$.  As for the statement itself, as written it is false since $2^1$ is not larger than $1^2 + 1$ and $2^2$ is not greater than $2^2+1$ so it fails for $n=1$ and $n=2$.  Now... for $n\geq 5$ however... it will be true, and the *fact that $n\geq 5$* will be a critical piece in proving (1).

Comment: Now, given that $n\geq 5$... are curious about proving $2n^2>n^2+2n+2$.  Well... $2n^2 = n^2+n^2$... just by splitting it up into two pieces.  Now, this right piece let's split up further... $n^2+n^2 = n^2 + n\times n$.  Since $n$ is in particular bigger than, say, $3$, we can continue by replacing one of those $n$'s so we are now at $n^2 + n\times n > n^2 + 3\times n$.  Splitting this up we are at $n^2 + 3\times n = n^2 + 2n + n$ and using that $n$ is big enough once more, we are at $n^2 + 2n + n > n^2 + 2n + 2$

Comment: Um... $2n^2 > 2n^2 + 2$?  That 's news to me....But $2n^2 = n^2 + n^2 = n^2 + n*n=n^2 + 2n + (n-2)*n=n^2 + 2n + 1+ [(n-2)*n -1] = (n+1)^2  + [(n-2)*n -1]  = (n+1)^2 + 1 +[(n-2)*n-2]$ and $(n+1)^2 + 1 +[(n-2)*n-2] > (n+1)^2 + 1$  ***!!!!IF!!!!!***  $(n-2)*n - 2 > 0$ i.e if $n^2-2n+1=(n-1)^2 > 3$ or if (assuming $n\ge 1$) if $n > \sqrt 3 + 1$.  So inducting step can only work if $n \ge 3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2n^2 > n^2 + 2n + 2$ is true only if $n \ge 3$.  Which as $n \ge 5$ is okay to assume.

$2n^2 = n^2 + n^2 = n^2 + n\cdot n \ge  n^2 + 3n =n^2 + 2n + n > n^2 + 2n + 2$.

that's all.

....

So

Base case:  $2^5 = 32$ and $5^2 + 1 = 26$ so $2^n > n^2 + 1$ for $n=5$.

Inductions case:  If $2^n > n^2 + 1$ then

$2^{n+1} = 2\cdot 2^n > 2\cdot (n^2 + 1)= 2n^2 + 2= n^2 + n^2 + 2$.  And as $n \ge 5$

$n^2 + n^2 + 2 \ge n^2 + 5n + 2=$

$n^2 + 2n + 3n+2 \ge n^2 + 2n + 17=$

$(n^2+2n + 1) + 16 = (n+1)^2 +16 > (n+1)^2 + 1$.

and that's the induction step.

======= Alternative answer=====

The induction step ought to be:

$2^n > (n+1)^2 + 1$ so $2^{n+1} = 2*2^n > 2(n^2 + 1) = 2n^2 + 2=$

$(n^2 + 2n + 1) + 1 + (n^2 - 2n)=(n+1)^2 + 1 +(n^2-2n) \ge (n+1)^2 + 1$

but this is only valid if $n^2 -2n \ge 0$  which is only true if $n^2-2n+1 =(n-1)^2 \ge 1$ or (as $n \ge 0$) if $n-1 \ge 1$ or $n \ge 2$.  So the induction step will work (but only work) if our base case is $n \ge 2$.

But $2^2 < 2^2 + 1$ and $2^3 < 3^2 + 1$ and $2^4 < 4^2 +1$ so we can't have *those* as our base case (especially as the statement isn't even true!).  But $2^5 > 5^2 + 1$ so $n=5$ could be our base case.

And as our induction step *is* valid for $n \ge 2$ are induction proof works... ***but*** we only proved it for $n \ge 5$

Answer (score 0):

(1) is equivalent to $n^2 - 2n + 1 > 3$. The left-hand side is $(n-1)^2$. As JMoravitz pointed out in the comments, you need an extra assumption $n \ge 3$ to prove (1).

Answer (score 0):

As @TheSilverDoe mentionned, the inequality is not true for 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. Strictly for the equation (1), you have the following:

For $n \geq 3$ (which includes $n \geq 5$), you have

$$n^2 > 2n + 2$$
$$\iff n^2 + n^2 > n^2 + 2n + 2$$
$$\iff 2n^2 > n^2 + 2n + 2$$

I hope this helps.